# Adding images to different poll question in django app - how to do?

Tags: django, image, addition

I have a django app up and running on PythonAnywhere and I want to add different pictures to different poll questions. How to do?

At the moment I have the same pictures for each poll question done by inserting a link to image in polls/detail.html

How to add code to have different pictue each time?

ie. page: polls/1 - will display picture 1, polls/2 picture 2 etc..

Answer (score 2):

Add an image to your Question model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    image:models.ImageField('upload_to'='images/')
    ...
```

and display that image.

```
<img src="{{ question.image.url  }}">
```